# Autofac's None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm back to Autofac issues despite using it in a very similar manner for over a year and really need some advise.

I choose to opt-in via attributes.  The difference this time is that one of the registrations uses IIndex to select the most appropriate interface for the task at hand based on a LoginState enum.  This value is provided via the attribute .

You could consider it a very basic Autofac based state-machine.

Due to the opt-in nature I have the following extension method which gets the type via the presence of the attribute and the value of the attribute:

```
public static class ContainerBuilderEnumerateAttributedTypes
{
    #region EnumerateAttributedTypes(builder, action)

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void EnumerateAttributedTypes<TAttribute>(this ContainerBuilder builder,
        Action<Type, TAttribute> action) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var typesAndAttributes = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(false).Any())
            .Select(type => new { Type = type, Attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(false).First() });

        foreach (var typeAndAtttribute in typesAndAttributes)
        {
            action(typeAndAtttribute.Type, typeAndAtttribute.Attribute);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region EnumerateAttributedTypes(builder, inherit, action)

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void EnumerateAttributedTypes<TAttribute>(this ContainerBuilder builder,
        bool inherit, Action<Type, TAttribute> action) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var typesAndAttributes = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(inherit).Any())
            .Select(type => new { Type = type, Attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(inherit).First() });

        foreach (var typeAndAtttribute in typesAndAttributes)
        {
            action(typeAndAtttribute.Type, typeAndAtttribute.Attribute);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

During Global.asax.cs I call builder.RegisterModule which in terms calls builder.RegisterModule.

In there I have the following:

```
public class LogicAutofacModule : Module
{
    #region Load

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.EnumerateAttributedTypes<DispatcherAttribute>((type, attribute) =>
        {
            var @interface = type.GetInterfaces().First();

            //  ReSharper disable once ConvertToLambdaExpression
            builder
                .RegisterType(type)
                .As(@interface);
        });

        builder.EnumerateAttributedTypes<LogicAttribute>((type, attribute) =>
        {
            var @interface = type.GetInterfaces().First();

            //  ReSharper disable once ConvertToLambdaExpression
            builder
                .RegisterType(type)
                .Keyed(attribute.State, @interface)
                .As(@interface);
        });
    }

    #endregion
```

There are two instances of IDispatcher are:

```
IIndex<LoginState, ILogic<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult>>
```

and

```
IIndex<LoginState, ILogic<AuthenticateIncurringChargeContext, AuthenticateIncurringChargeResult>> _handlers;
```

The LoginState if specified via a attribute, when applicable, via a

[LogicDispatcher(LogicState.InvalidCredentials)]

and similar.

No matter how I do this, even falling back to the most basic way of registering I get the 'None of the constructors found with

```
Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder error message.
```

Never had this before... please advise or ask for more info.

Afterthought...  here is an example of the ILogic implementation:

```
[Logic(LoginState.InvalidAccount)]
public class AuthenticateInvalidAccount : ILogic<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult>
{
    #region Execute

    public AuthenticateResult Execute(AuthenticateContext context, LoginResponse response)
    {
        return new AuthenticateResult
        {
            State = State.InvalidAccount
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And an instance of a dispatcher:

```
[Dispatcher]
public class AuthenticateDispatcher : IDispatcher<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult>
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IIndex<LoginState, ILogic<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult>> _handlers; 

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public AuthenticateDispatcher(IIndex<LoginState, ILogic<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult>> handlers)
    {
        _handlers = handlers;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dispatch

    public AuthenticateResult Dispatch(AuthenticateContext context)
    {
        var service = new AccountServiceClient();

        var response = service.Invoke(client => client.Login(context.Username, context.Password));

        var logic = _handlers[response.LoginState];

        var result = logic.Execute(context, response);

        return result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The service super simple:

```
[ErrorHandled]
public class Service : IService
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IDispatcher<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult> _authenticateDispatcher;

    private readonly IDispatcher<AuthenticateIncurringChargeContext, AuthenticateIncurringChargeResult> _authenticateIncurringChargeDispatcher;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public Service(
        IDispatcher<AuthenticateContext, AuthenticateResult> authenticateDispatcher,
        IDispatcher<AuthenticateIncurringChargeContext, AuthenticateIncurringChargeResult> authenticateIncurringChargeDispatcher)
    {
        _authenticateDispatcher = authenticateDispatcher;
        _authenticateIncurringChargeDispatcher = authenticateIncurringChargeDispatcher;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Authenticate

    public AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest request)
    {
        var context = request.Map<AuthenticateContext>();

        var result = _authenticateDispatcher.Dispatch(context);

        var response = result.Map<AuthenticateResponse>();

        return response;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region AuthenticateIncurringCharge

    public AuthenticateIncurringChargeResponse AuthenticateIncurringCharge(AuthenticateIncurringChargeRequest request)
    {
        //var context = request.Map<AuthenticateIncurringChargeContext>();

        //var result = _authenticateIncurringChargeDispatcher.Dispatch(context);

        //var response = result.Map<AuthenticateIncurringChargeResponse>();

        //return response;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather embarrassed.  Commented out the code that registered the logic services.  Ashamed :(

Hope someone finds the extension method useful however!